# Install gem gives "Failed to build gem native extension."

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I did: `sudo apt-get install ruby ruby-dev`.

And i run: `sudo gem install jekyll`.

But it gives this output:

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error
>   installing jekyll:    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/ruby2.1 -r ./siteconf20151018-15792-1gfjwox.rb extconf.rb creating Makefile
> ```
>
> make "DESTDIR=" clean sh: 1: make: not found
>
> make "DESTDIR=" sh: 1: make: not found
>
> make failed, exit code 127
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/fast-stemmer-1.0.2 for inspection. Results
>   logged to
>   /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/fast-stemmer-1.0.2/gem_make.out

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to install `make` and other build tools first, run this:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Answer (score 0):

```
make: not found
```

This means that the program `make` (that is used to build libraries from code) is not present on your machine. You should try to install it with your package manager.

```
sudo apt-get cmake
```

might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install build-essential solves the issue for mysql gem failing due to make program failure for linux.